# MySQL join to return distinct IDs linked from another table

Tags: mysql, join

Let's say I have three tables:

**LOCATIONS** - a store can belong to multiple locations and a location can have multiple stores

```
+-------------+----------+
| LOCATION_ID | STORE_ID |
+-------------+----------+
```

**STORES** - only one row per store, every store has only one manager ID

```
+----------+------------+
| STORE_ID | MANAGER_ID |
+----------+------------+
```

**EMPLOYEES** - a manager can have multiple employees, and employees can belong to more than one manager

```
+-------------+-------------+
| MANAGER_ID  | EMPLOYEE_ID |
+-------------+-------------+
```

And for a given location (e.g. LOCATION_ID = 999), I want to get all the employees managed at stores at that location.

This gets me the list of managers that belong to stores in that location:

```
SELECT s.MANAGER_ID FROM LOCATIONS l
  INNER JOIN STORES s 
     ON s.STORE_ID = l.STORE_ID 
  WHERE l.LOCATION_ID = 999;
```

What I actually want is ALL the distinct EMPLOYEE_IDs that are linked to the managers that query spits out.

What additional join can I add in the same query to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.EMPLOYEE_ID 
FROM LOCATIONS L  
INNER JOIN STORES S ON S.STORE_ID = L.STORE_ID   
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON S.MANAGER_ID = E.MANAGER_ID 
WHERE L.LOCATION_ID = 999;
```

Comment: Weird, I thought I tried this exact thing but it only returned one EMPLOYEE_ID per MANAGER, clearly I messed something up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `INNER JOIN Employees e ON s.MANAGER_ID = e.MANAGER_ID` should get you the employees.

But I notice you're asking for how to *select* all the distinct employee IDs. Change your SELECT clause to `SELECT DISTINCT e.EMPLOYEE_ID`, rather than returning the store managers' IDs.

RedFilter's answer spells it out nicely. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID ... INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES e ON e.MANAGER_ID = s.MANAGER_ID ...
```

You can add the DISTINCT keyword before the employee ID, however if the data is properly normalized that shouldn't be necessary.